# Why can't I find the redis module for langchain vectorstores?

Tags: python, redis, langchain

I am trying to just simply store some embeddings that I have already generated using a Redis container. I get the error on import..

```
from langchain.vectorstores.redis import Redis
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.vectorstores.redis'
```

This is from attempting to follow the tutorial listed here: https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/vectorstores/examples/redis.html

Also I am on python 3.8.0 if this matters.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You might try phrasing title as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure lol, this is the best I got

Comment: What version of langchain are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.0.27

Comment: I have tried versions 0.0.17 and 0.0.18 and receive the same error.

Comment: can you share the filename from which you are trying to import the langchain module? also the related files (names) with that also?

Comment: is that `langchain.py` somehow? the file in which you are trying to import the vectorstore?

Comment: I would imagine the __init__ of vectorstore.py However redis is nowhere to be found there.

I will implement my own Redis vectorstore today I guess

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an old/outdated version of `langchain`? I can find the `Redis` module here: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/vectorstores/__init__.py

Try using latest version:

```bash
pip install -U redis langchain==0.0.184
```

And then you should be able to import it with:

```py
from langchain.vectorstores import Redis
```